# Как отображать и убирать компоненты

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Я таким образом делаю:

```
const {isDisplayRegistration , setIsDisplayRegistration} = useContext(RegistrationContext);
    
{isDisplayRegistration ? <Registration/> : ''}
```

Так правильно делать?

Comment: Можно `{isDisplayRegistration && <Registration/>}`

Comment: Просто мне кажется если использовать такой подход отображения компонентов то это усложнит читаемость кода